# I need to make a reference to a JLabel based off a string

Tags: java

So I have numbered JLabels declared like so (In the class)
OP_1
OP_2
OP_3
etc..

And I have a number and a string.

What I want is that when, for example, the number is 2. I want to change the label text to the content of the string. This is part of a method that is supposed to take a string, put it into the last available JLabel, and then increment the number.

I am very confused, and help would be appreciated.

Comment: How could you compare or convert a number to a JLabel. However, you may compare each JLabel's text to match with the number. If, a match found, get the reference to JLabel and then change the text with content of the string.

Comment: Not converting anything. I am changing the Label's text to what is in the string. It's the label's name that needs to be found using a number.

Comment: yes, you are trying to compare a number with JLabel's text, So. anyhow you need a reference to that matching JLabel. For that, you need to compare text of all the JLabel's text. there s no other way to solve your problem.

Comment: JLabels have text, which shows up onscreen, and names, which you use to reference them in the code. To make the question even simpler, I need to access the JLabel with a string that contains it's name so I can edit the text that shows up onscreen,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I created an array of JLabels and a method, updateNextLabel(String), which will update the next JLabel with whatever you enter for str.

```
public class Example {
    static int count = 0; //Create a count
    static JLabel[] array = new JLabel[3]; //Create an array to hold all three JLabels

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Set the default text for each JLabel
        array[0] = new JLabel("This is OP1");
        array[1] = new JLabel("This is OP2");
        array[2] = new JLabel("This is OP3");
        //Here is an example if you wanted to use a for-loop to update the JLabels
        for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
            updateNextLabel("This is the new text for OP" + (count + 1));
            System.out.println(array[x].getText());
        }
    }

    public static void updateNextLabel(String str) {
        array[count].setText(str);
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of / additional to naming your labels by specific names you can later match them on, I'd think a `Map` of `JLabel`s with `String`s or `Integer`s as keys might be a better approach:

```
Map<String,JLabel> labelMap = new HashMap<String,JLabel>();
labelMap.put("1", OP_1);
labelMap.put("2", OP_2);
```

This will allow later access of "The label for key `2`" as well as "list me all that labels and find the one with text `2`" as well